# If I update a table's row which is also a row in a View, will the view's row be updated as well?

Tags: mysql, sql, view, sql-update

If I update a table's row which is also a row in a View, will the view's row be updated as well? I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

**YES**. Well, a `VIEW` is just a stored query which mimics a table.  So any changes on the table will also be followed on the view

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a view should be viewed as essentially a stored SELECT statement. Any changes in the data on the underlying table will be reflected directly in the view.

If you think about it, if it were not then Views would need to store a replication of the data at the point the the view was created.